# how to manage port number in deploying a window service hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

Sorry if this sounds very simple but I am very new to wcf/network so please bear with me.

I want to deploy a window service hosted WCF service to three servers (Dev, UAT, Prod) hence the endpoint url for each server needs to be stored in database so that deployment can be automated using a script. The window service does nothing but hosting the wcf service and when it starts, I set the endpoint url to be localhost:8081/MyCompnay/MyService and simply use a default BasicHttpBinding to pass into the service host constructor. I am currently choosing a random port number (8080 is almost for sure in use already), I wonder what's the optimal way of managing port number in such a case that the service will be deployed to different servers? I am concerned that even if I make the port number configurable, it could happen that the same port number might be taken by some other applications when my service is restarted after a shutdown (for whatever reason!). I want to be sure that the port number I set won't be taken by other applications.
Hope I have made this clear.

Comment: Have you looked at deployment options? Check out [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx) on using transformations to make deployments easy. I'm guessing what you want to do can be done using this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never a guarantee that the port number will not be taken. You could have a series of port numbers that you try and work your way through them until you find one that works.  If you don't find one that works then you error out and inform the user.  Choose port numbers above 49151 as these are considered [private ports](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335#section-8.1.2).

If you don't need the HTTP binding, you could use a Named Pipe binding that doesn't require a port, but there are different limitations to using that as well.

There is also the option of registering your port number with the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) and then anyone using your port is technically the bad app, but there is no preventing it.  This is overkill for a good majority of applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm facing another problem on port number. I initially can't start my window service (which acts as a host to the wcf service) on a server and the error is "Your process doesn't have permission to the HTTP namespace". Then I asked our admin to change the account used to log on the window service to be a local admin account.

Comment: After this account upgrade, the window service can be started on the server but the server is not listening to the wcf service url I set in the window service OnStart() method. So I rebooted the server, now I got a different error which is: The TCP port number (contained in the url address where I want the wcf service to be listened on) is being used another application already. I am pretty sure that the port number is not being used according to netstat -a but no matter what port number I try it always gives the same error: the port number is being used by another application. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is it possible something started before your app, using that port, and subsequently stopped.  If you start the app again, does it run?